# Dynamically loading CSS and JS files in main Page

Tags: javascript, dynamic, load

i have some js and css files now my requirement to keep these link in xml files and apply on aspx page when page get load can anybody please help to do this

css Links :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ed/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

js links :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

xml File: i am not suer the way of writing xml file is correct or not

```
<editor>
<template1>
<theme id="1" name="default">
<css><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ed/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</css>
<js>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
</js>
</theme>
</template1>
</editor>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the browser to dynamically load these files after being passed the XML file?

If so then use a combination of ajax to load the xml file, then something like Modernizr.load to load the files.

http://modernizr.com/docs/#load

If the xml file is used on the server-side I guess just print the various links and scripts into your header before it's sent to the browser.